# deploying ruby + sinatra app on google appengine

Tags: ruby, google-app-engine, sinatra, jruby, jruby-rack

I am trying to deploy a ruby + sinatra app in google appengine. The deployment process with appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4 seems to end ok but when I access the application url I get this error:

```
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: uninitialized constant Java::ComGoogleApphostingRuntimeSecuritySharedStubJavaLang::ProcessBuilder::Redirect
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

oldie but let's have it answered - was just revisiting a work-around in JRuby ...

GAE doesn't white-list *java.lang.ProcessBuilder* (class simply isn't available)

JRuby has since fixed the issue: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/1148
(backticks works around ProcessBuilder not being available)